Is there an elementary set with positive Lebesgue measure in any rectangle of the plane, where the measures don’t equal the area of the rectangles?
Suppose $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is Borel and $B$ is a rectangle of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In addition, suppose the Lebesgue measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is $\lambda(\cdot)\;\!$:

Question: How do we define explicit $A$, such that:

$\lambda(A\cap B)>0$ for all $B$
$\lambda(A\cap B)\neq\lambda(B)$ for all $B$?


For a potential answer, see this reddit post. (It seems the answer is correct; however, I wonder if there's a simpler version that is less annoying to prove.)
